# ORA-12537 when invoking bulk Merge - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, bulkinsert, odp.net

I'm trying to insert/update many records using ArrayBindCount.

It works just fine for 1 and 2 records, but if I try to insert **3** or more I get a **ORA-12537** exception.

I'm using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll** version **4.121.1.0**.
I tried on **OracleXE 11g** and **Oracle Standard 11g** too.

This is the sql I'm using:

```
MERGE INTO tb_medidor_ene t1 
USING (select :pId cd_medidor, :pDate dt_hr_instante, :pValor vl_eneat_del from dual) t2 ON (t1.cd_medidor = t2.cd_medidor and t1.dt_hr_instante = t2.dt_hr_instante) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN update set t1.vl_eneat_del = t2.vl_eneat_del, dt_hr_insercao = :pInsertDate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t1.cd_medidor, t1.dt_hr_insercao, t1.dt_hr_instante, t1.vl_eneat_del) 
VALUES (t2.cd_medidor, :pInsertDate, t2.dt_hr_instante, t2.vl_eneat_del)
```

And this (simplified) code:

```
    int num = 3;
    int index;
    var ids = new int[num];
    var insertDates = new DateTime[num];
    var dates = new DateTime[num];
    var values = new double[num];

    for (index = 0; index < num; index++) {
        ids[index] = 1;
        insertDates[index] = DateTime.Now;
        dates[index] = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(index * 5);
        values[index] = index;
    }
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(Program.ConnString)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand()) {
            command.ArrayBindCount = num;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.BindByName = true;
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pId", ids));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pInsertDate", insertDates));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pDate", dates));
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pValor", values));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

"An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

{"ORA-12537: Biblioteca de Rede: Fim do arquivo"}

### Stack trace:

at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(OracleTraceLevel level, OracleTraceTag tag, Exception ex)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int32 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean& bAllPureInputBinds, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Boolean bDefineDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int32 lobPrefetchSize, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at OraclePlayground.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\dev\way2\DataIn\OraclePlayground\OraclePlayground\Program.cs:line 114
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I am having the same problem but my limit is 4. From 5 merge statements on I get the same error. Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @mosu see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks andrecarlucci but that is a workaround I would prefer not to use. I used a batch command instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone with the same problem:

I ended up creating a stored procedure that does nothing but execute the same SQL I was trying to execute directly.

You can then bulk call the procedure and it works fine.

So far, this is the only way to do it until the Oracle guys fix the issue.

Comment: Another alternative is to just execute Merge statement in a for loop. I know that it is not bulk operation and it will be slower but at least it will work with version 4.121.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Merged items causing a ORA-12537 error.  It was odd because it worked for a while, then did not.  I eventually narrowed it down to null values in a CLOB field.  It would work if only one value of the CLOB was null, but if there was more than one, it would consistently die.  I resolved it by changing it to put a space into the CLOB (even using '' caused an error). Waste of a space, but at least the error is gone.

This seems like a bug to me.  I am running Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 64-bit locally.  Hope this helps...